# How to access state of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have home component with header component how may I access the header states in home component here is the example

**Header.JS**

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageNumber: 1
        }
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="shopping-list">
        <ul>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from './header';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <Header /> // I need to use the states of Header in this component
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

I need to use the states of Header in Home component, is that possible?

Does this way is good for performance?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  [`state lifting`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Define a method e.g. `liftTheState` in `Header` component which will lift the state of `Header` component by calling `Home` component method with required data.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageNumber: 1
        }
    }

  liftTheState=()=>{

      this.props.callHomeMethod(this.state.pageNumber);
  }
  render() {
    //...
  }
}
```

In Home :

Define a method   e.g. `callHomeMethod` in `Home` component which will hold the `Header` component data and passed the method as a prop to `Header` component

```
class App extends Component {

    callHomeMethod = (someDataFromHeader)=>{


    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <Header  callHomeMethod = {this.callHomeMethod}/> // pass Home method here used for state lifting.
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very smart solution, I did as you did I tried to console.log the someDataFromHeader like 
`callHomeMethod = (someDataFromHeader)=>{
    console.log(someDataFromHeader, 'it doesn't give me a result of pageNumber);
    }` Is it like this way how we use it

Comment: @Lauradelgado `someDataFromHeader ` should print data

Comment: I did an example, please check it out. Thank you [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lllnj4ky9z)

Comment: @Lauradelgado updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/2zo37mj44j.You need to call `liftTheState` from somwhere or using some event mechanism

Comment: Okay that's awesome! Thank you